# Display video url from mysql database to listview

Tags: android, mysql

I'm working on an App in which I want to display video stored in mysql databsae into a listivew using videos URL's like:
[description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbw9b.png)

I have followed many tutorials and also searched here and didn t find the solution yet.All tutorials are about how to display images in a listivew not a video.

Any suggestions I would highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the video just a photo from server or Preprepared 。so when you click the photo(the users think it is a video),then play the video by the vid or url,This is your confusion？

Comment: No friend the user clicks directly on the video not the image

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use this link for playing the `video in the recyclerview`.

[Click here](https://github.com/eneim/Toro)

For the `SQLlite Database` follow this tutorial

[Click Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks very much android_griezmann i will try it soon and post my reply